# Space came between digits in jQgrid when showing total number of records in the end

Tags: jqgrid

The jQgrid list  shows a space between the first and second digit when the number of items are in to 4 digits. For example, when I was viewing, there were 3956 users and it was displaying on the right side bottom part of the table as ‘3 956’.

Answer (score 4):

The space as the separator will be shown because of wrong value of `thousandsSeparator` value in `grid.locale-en.js` file. This is correct for Bulgarian (the developer of jqGrid come from Bulgarian), but looks strange for you.

Yo can modify the value `thousandsSeparator` from " " to "," in the `grid.locale-en.js` file file or make the following changes

```
$.jgrid.formatter.integer.thousandsSeparator=',';
$.jgrid.formatter.number.thousandsSeparator=',';
$.jgrid.formatter.currency.thousandsSeparator=',';
```

before the first call of `jqGrid`.

If you want you can use no separator ('') instead of the comma (',').